Xcodebuild: error: Timed out waiting for all destinations matching the provided destination specifier to become available
I am getting this error while running flutter app in iPhone 15 Pro Max
Whole error log:
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    xcodebuild: error: Timed out waiting for all destinations matching the provided destination specifier to become available


        Ineligible destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
            { platform:iOS, arch:arm64, id:-, name:Harsh’s iPhone, error:Device is busy (Preparing Harsh’s iPhone) }

Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/dx/r0gn/T/flutter_tools.YsAMBm/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirnwhvVK/temporary_xcresult_bundle

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on Harsh’s iPhone.

I want to run flutter app on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
Note: app build successfully on emulator and Android phones.

If you have a VPN enabled, just turn it off.

Thanks @reacct, but it's not working

@NipulRathod how is this unclear?
